# Replace Datatype/Timestamp C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timestamp

I have a query i get back after i split the right reccords and this all works fine but i get       the Datetime and Timestamp reccords back without separators like:

**"20140411085345"** but what i need is **"2014/04/11 08:53:45"**

Can anyone help me?

thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Sorry maybe i need to be more clear:

i have a query:

```
Select * from Table
```

i use these reccords to copy them to an other database.
but while i get  the records back the Datatype's Datetime and  Timestamp
give all reccords without separators so what i need is that the Datetime and Timestamp datatype's get the separators between them if they get selected.

Comment: What query exactly? `20140411085345` is a `string` type?

Comment: What kind of query? (Database? WMI? …) Do you know what time zone applies?

Comment: If 20140411085345 is string you could use substring and create the diseried datetime.

Comment: Please show your code - we have no idea where you're getting the data from or what you're doing with it at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is simply how to convert one format to another, you can use `DateTime.ParseExact()` to get a `DateTime` first, then format it to whatever you'd like...

```
var input = "20140411085345";
var timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", null);
var output = timestamp.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/fcreZA

Comment: this is something i like it. but this is hardcoded. i got a string that i get back with many fields like firstname,lastname ... and in that string the records i want to do this with are the reccords of the  datatype Datetime and Timestamp